# Java - Action Listener of JRadioButton name

Tags: java, namespaces, radio-button, actionlistener

How can I add an ActionListener to the name of an element?

I have a loop which creates a table for me.

[image]

In this loop i create the radio buttons:

```
ZFbutton = new JRadioButton();
ZFbutton.setName(""+key);
```

..where `key` is from the loop.

Currently I try to access the JRadioButtons via:

```
 ZFbutton.addActionListener (new ActionListener () {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      try {
         if(ZFbutton.isSelected() == true){
```

but this only lets me access the last created JRadioButton, which makes sense from a logic perspective. So i gave every RadioButton a unique name: `ZFbutton.setName(""+key);` but how can I make an ActionListener with the name of the element?.

Comment: their are several ways you can try. 1st is to check which element causes the action event with `e.getSource()`and maybe `.getName()`  works on the source. other way is to store the radiobuttons in an array and access them via the array

Comment: I'd recommend using a `JTable` instead

Comment: @XtremeBaumer Thank you i made an array out of it that fixed my problem. You could write it as answer so i can accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add all buttons to an array and access each of them through it. its an easy way, but what @StimpsonCat mentioned should work as well.

```
JRadioButoon[] buttons=new JRadioButton[x];
buttons[0]=new JRadioButton();
...
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add actionListener to each of the buttons. Instead of setting the Button's name you could set an ActionCommand for it.

```
button.setActionCommand("Alpha");
```

Then you can distiguish which button was pressed like this:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
String ac = ae.getActionCommand();

if (ac.equals("Alpha")) {
  if (jbtnB.isEnabled()) {
    System.out.println("Alpha pressed. Beta is disabled.");
    jbtnB.setEnabled(false);
  } else {
    System.out.println("Alpha pressed. Beta is enabled.");
    jbtnB.setEnabled(true);
  }
} else if (ac.equals("Beta"))
  System.out.println("Beta pressed.");
}
```

You get the actionCommand from the actionEvent.